# Why can't I access errorInfo and errorCode

Tags: tcl

I have the following code:

```
$ cat ~/tmp/2.tcl
set zero 0
proc p1 {} {
    if {[catch {expr 1/$zero} err]} {
        puts "errorCode=$errorCode"
        puts "errorInfo=$errorInfo"
    }
}

p1
```

When I source it, I get error accessing errorCode:

```
$ tclsh ~/tmp/2.tcl
can't read "errorCode": no such variable
    while executing
"puts "errorCode=$errorCode""
    (procedure "p1" line 3)
    invoked from within
"p1"
    (file "~/tmp/2.tcl" line 9)
```

I tried changing to $::errorCode, but did not help.

Can you see what is wrong?

Comment: Works fine for me once the variable names are qualified (e.g. `::errorCode` instead of just `errorCode`). Note that you need to qualify `zero` as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `errorInfo` and `errorCode` variables are globals. You should either use the `global` command to bring them into scope or use their fully-qualified names (i.e., precede with `::`).

It might be easier to pick the information out of the result options dictionary (a new feature in 8.5).

Answer (score 4):

<s>Starting from Tcl 8.5 `[catch]` doesn't set the `errorCode` and `errorInfo` global variables.</s> (As Donal has pointed out, it still does, so they can be accessed as `$::errorCode` and `$::errorInfo`). And in addition it puts their values into a dictionary which name is to be specified as the third argument. The following code

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh

set zero 0
proc p1 {} {
    if {[catch {expr 1/$zero} err opts] == 1} {
        puts "errorCode=[dict get $opts -errorcode]"
        puts "errorInfo=[dict get $opts -errorinfo]"
    }
}

p1
```

prints

```
errorCode=NONE
errorInfo=can't read "zero": no such variable
    while executing
"expr 1/$zero"
```

in Tcl 8.5.19, and

```
errorCode=TCL READ VARNAME
errorInfo=can't read "zero": no such variable
    while executing
"expr 1/$zero"
```

in Tcl8.6.6.

You'd probably want to use `$::zero` in the division after which the result would be

```
errorCode=ARITH DIVZERO {divide by zero}
errorInfo=divide by zero
    while executing
"expr 1/$::zero"
```

Comment: The variables are still set. They're also still _globals_.

Comment: Right, thank you for clarification. I've edited the answer.

Comment: And now your answer is correct and useful, so I can vote it up.

Answer (score 0):

Sergei's answer is very good. Using the dictionary returned by the second optional parameter of `catch [...]` is spot on. However, I find slightly different entries in this dictionary and -errorinfo is not one of them.

There are only two dictionary entries in *opts*. What works for me is

```
puts "errorCode=[dict get $opts -code]"
puts "errorLevel=[dict get $opts -level]"
```

Perhaps I have an older or more specialized version of Tcl/Tk?

Comment: Content of `$opts` after `[catch]` depends on what you catches. Which was the contents of `[catch]` in your specific case?

Comment: You're right. Thanks. `opts` from the `[catch]` seems to depend on what arguments are used in, for example the `return` statement of a procedure called inside the `[catch ...]` Found a general pattern and summarized some findings in the next answer here.

Answer (score 0):

The options dictionary from the result of a `[catch ...]` seem to contain various elements in a curious pattern depending on the `-code` and `-level` of what threw the exception inside the `[catch]`. A few examples follow:

```
rc=0 catch.rslt=XXX catch.opts=-code 0 -level 0
rc=1 catch.rslt=XXX catch.opts=-code 1 -level 0 -errorinfo {A B C foo rvdebug.cfg 223} -errorcode {1 2 C}
rc=2 catch.rslt=XXX catch.opts=-code 0 -level 0
rc=3 catch.rslt=XXX catch.opts=-code 3 -level 0
rc=4 catch.rslt=XXX catch.opts=-code 4 -level 0
rc=0 catch.rslt=XXX catch.opts=-code 0 -level 0
rc=1 catch.rslt=XXX catch.opts=-code 1 -level 0 -errorinfo {A B C} -errorcode {1 2 C}
rc=2 catch.rslt=XXX catch.opts=-code 0 -level 0
rc=3 catch.rslt=XXX catch.opts=-code 3 -level 0
rc=4 catch.rslt=XXX catch.opts=-code 4 -level 0
rc=2 catch.rslt=XXX catch.opts=-code 0 -level 1
rc=2 catch.rslt=XXX catch.opts=-code 1 -level 1
rc=2 catch.rslt=XXX catch.opts=-code 2 -level 1
rc=2 catch.rslt=XXX catch.opts=-code 3 -level 1
rc=2 catch.rslt=XXX catch.opts=-code 4 -level 1
```

For example, a throwable procedure ...

```
proc foo {c lvl} {
  return -code $c \
         -errorinfo [list A B C] \
         -errorcode [list 1 2 C] \
         -level $lvl XXX \
}
```

... is called by a catchable handler ...

```
set rc [catch {foo 0 0} rslt opts]
```

... and its results examined as

```
echo "rc=$rc catch.rslt=$rslt catch.opts=$opts"
```

To summarize,

- `return` allows `-errorcode` only when `-code` is 1 (TCL_ERROR) and `-level` is 0 (TRACE_TOP), otherwise syntax error
- `catch` opts always contain the two elements `-code` and `-level`
- `catch` opts has `-errorinfo` suffixed with func,file,line only when `-code` is 1 (TCL_ERROR) and `-level` is 0 (TRACE_TOP)
- `catch` opts has `-errorinfo` un-suffixed only when `-code` is 1 (TCL_ERROR) and `-level` is 1 (TRACE_SUBTOP)
- `catch` opts sets `-code` as 0 only when `-code` is 2 (TCL_RETURN) and `-level` is 0 or 1 (TRACE_TOP or TRACE_SUBTOP)
- `catch` always returns 2 (TCL_RETURN) when `-level` is more than 1 (below TRACE_SUBTOP)
- `catch` returns `-code` when `-level` is 0 or 1 (TRACE_TOP or TRACE_SUBTOP), and is not set to 0 at `-code` 2 (TCL_RETURN)
- `catch` returns rslt unless proc is called with or has "wrong # args", a message returned instead along with `-code` set to 1 (TCL_ERROR)

where

```
# -code TCL_OK | TCL_ERROR | TCL_RETURN | TCL_BREAK | TCL_CONTINUE
# -level trace-depth-of-call-stack  -- non-negative number
# -errorinfo [list ... ... ...]     -- trio of elements meaning, e.g., proc, file, linenum
# -errorcode [list ...]             -- arbitrary information, alphanumeric, one or more
# -errorinfo in catch opts only when -code is 1 (TCL_ERROR) and -level is 0 (TRACE_TOP) or 1 (TRACE_SUBTOP), value is dflt-trace unless -errorinfo specified  --> ::errorInfo
# -errorcode in catch opts only when -code is 1 (TCL_ERROR) and -level is 0 (TRACE_TOP) or 1 (TRACE_SUBTOP), value is NONE unless -errorcode specified        --> ::errorCode
```

and

```
# TCL Return Codes: TCL_OK 0 TCL_ERROR 1 TCL_RETURN 2 TCL_BREAK 3 TCL_CONTINUE 4
# TCL Trace Levels: TRACE_TOP 0 TRACE_SUBTOP 1 ... ...
```

In my particular case of OpenOCD presumably a simpler and/or older version of jim-tcl is used, where the `return` allows only four arguments:

```
# return ?-code code? ?-errorinfo stacktrace? ?-level level? ?result?
```

Thus, neither `-errorstack [list ...]` nor `-options [dict create ... ...]` are supported for any `-code` or `-level`.

```
The MWE which created this output is shown below.
```

proc foo {c lvl} { return -code $c -errorinfo [list A B C] -errorcode [list 1 2 C] -level $lvl XXX}
set rc [catch {foo 0 0} rslt opts] ; echo "rc=$rc catch.rslt=$rslt catch.opts=$opts"
set rc [catch {foo 1 0} rslt opts] ; echo "rc=$rc catch.rslt=$rslt catch.opts=$opts"
set rc [catch {foo 2 0} rslt opts] ; echo "rc=$rc catch.rslt=$rslt catch.opts=$opts"
set rc [catch {foo 3 0} rslt opts] ; echo "rc=$rc catch.rslt=$rslt catch.opts=$opts"
set rc [catch {foo 4 0} rslt opts] ; echo "rc=$rc catch.rslt=$rslt catch.opts=$opts"

set rc [catch {foo 0 1} rslt opts] ; echo "rc=$rc catch.rslt=$rslt catch.opts=$opts"
set rc [catch {foo 1 1} rslt opts] ; echo "rc=$rc catch.rslt=$rslt catch.opts=$opts"
set rc [catch {foo 2 1} rslt opts] ; echo "rc=$rc catch.rslt=$rslt catch.opts=$opts"
set rc [catch {foo 3 1} rslt opts] ; echo "rc=$rc catch.rslt=$rslt catch.opts=$opts"
set rc [catch {foo 4 1} rslt opts] ; echo "rc=$rc catch.rslt=$rslt catch.opts=$opts"

set rc [catch {foo 0 2} rslt opts] ; echo "rc=$rc catch.rslt=$rslt catch.opts=$opts"
set rc [catch {foo 1 2} rslt opts] ; echo "rc=$rc catch.rslt=$rslt catch.opts=$opts"
set rc [catch {foo 2 2} rslt opts] ; echo "rc=$rc catch.rslt=$rslt catch.opts=$opts"
set rc [catch {foo 3 2} rslt opts] ; echo "rc=$rc catch.rslt=$rslt catch.opts=$opts"
set rc [catch {foo 4 2} rslt opts] ; echo "rc=$rc catch.rslt=$rslt catch.opts=$opts"